# How to extract svg tag from svg image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, svg, extract

We are using `<img>` tag to display svg images right now

```
<div class="info-vis-img">
    <img alt="infovisual-mobile-printing-1" src="/-/media/Infovisual/infovisual-mobile-printing-1.svg" class="text-center">
</div>
```

but now we don't wanna use `<img>` tag to display svg images instead we want to extract svg tag from svg image and will place extracted svg tag inside `<div>` tag as shown below.

```
<div class="info-vis-img">
    <div class="svg-icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="449.1 991.8 33.6 33.6">
          <path d="M482.7 1007.8h-16v-16h-1.6v16h-16v1.6h16v16h1.6v-16h16v-1.6z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can we achieve this. Is there any plugin or API available which take svg image path as an input parameter and return `<svg>` tag

Thanks

Comment: Awesome...I was looking for exactly that kind of

Comment: the only concern here is that it's executing client side so this might have little impact on page load response time...Can we do the same in server side through any C#.net API / plugin or any other approach...otherwise we are good this one...